# SheetJS xlsx-cell styling node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, formatting

I'm trying to format the text, inserting fields in bold and adding the filter in the boxes.

the excel file is generated correctly with the data but without any formatting .. can you tell me why?

```
const XLSX = require('@sheet/core')
const workbook_users = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      var users = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([['id', 'unit_id', 'Azienda', 'Nome', 'Cognome', 'Mail', 'Telefono', 'Indirizzo', 'Citta', 'province', 'Nazione', 'CAP', 'Ruolo', 'Data', 'Tipo di buono', 'Saldo'], ...reportData]);
      users['A1'].s = {
        font: {
            name: 'arial',
            sz: 224,
            bold: true,
            color: "#F2F2F2"
        },
    }
    
      XLSX.utils.sheet_set_range_style(users, 'A1:P1') 
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook_users, users, "rpt_user");
      users['!autofilter'] = { ref: "A1:E1" };

      const workBookBuffer1 = XLSX.write(workbook_users, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
      zip.addFile('rpt_user.xlsx', workBookBuffer1)
```